# Which case would be the appropriate usage of "tap" operator?

Tags: rxjs

According to the docs or other documents, they say, `do/tap` operator can be used in the below circumstance:

> Transparently perform actions or side-effects, such as logging.

Now, my example:

```
someStream$.pipe(
  map(({a1, a2}: {a1: number, a2: string}) => {
     this.doSomething(a1, a2);
     return {a1, a2};
  })
);
```

In `doSomething` method, I do some operation which has nothing to do with any transformation of the value I get from the source stream. So it got me thinking, it could be considered as side-effect and I could possibly outsource it to `tap` operator and just pass through the object `{a1, a2}` afterward. But I'm still not sure if it's an appropriate usage of `tap` operator. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: IMO, you should definitely be using `tap` here, as the `map` - as you've written it - appears to perform no mapping/transformation.

Comment: @cartant I get that `map` operator doesn't suit here but is `tap` appropriate in this case?

Comment: Yep. That's what it's for.

Comment: @cartant Gotcha! Thanks man